# How to access hostvars from goss test with molecule

Tags: molecule

I have a molecule scenario that creates 3 docker instances, each having a different configuration from the same role. The three communicates with each other as I put the instances IP addresses in their respective configuration files.

I need to test that the correct IP address is set the config files of each instance.

How can I access ansible group and host variables from goss?

Comment: What's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since goss can use variables from a yaml or json file, I just modified the `verify.yml` example playbook to export this variable and use it in the goss command.

```
- name: Verify
  hosts: all
  become: true
  vars:
    [...]
    goss_vars: "{{ goss_test_directory }}/vars"
  tasks:
    [...]
    - name: Register hostvars
      copy:
        content: "{'hostvars': {{ hostvars }}}"
        dest: "{{ goss_vars }}"

    - name: Execute Goss tests
      command: "{{ goss_bin }} --vars {{ goss_vars }} -g {{ item }} validate --format {{ goss_format }}"
      register: test_results
      with_items: "{{ test_files.stdout_lines }}"
      failed_when: false

    [...]
```

Then the variable is available in goss test files as `{{ .Vars.hostvars }}`.